# rsync from MacOS to Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, rsync, cp

I'm trying to rsync some files from my macbook to an ubuntu laptop ( `ole@192.168.9.36` ) using this command:

```
rsync -vazh ~/Folder ole@192.168.9.36
```

But instead of syncing the files to the remote host, it creates the folder `ole@192.168.9.36`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK - So this works:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh ~/Folder ole@192.168.9.36:/home/ole/
```

The important part is this:

```
:/home/ole/
```

If I leave the directory path off on the destination, it creates the directory instead.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to specify a remote path, but you do have to specify the ":" -- that's the delimiter between user@host and the path, and anything that doesn't have that delimiter is implicitly a (local) path.